# How to align the text in div bootstrap grid to bottom?

Tags: html, css

This is the sample code what i had done.

https://jsfiddle.net/gnqpbmrd/6/

How can i align the text to bottom of div? I want the date to be bottom of the div.

```
vertical-align:bottom
```

I tried to align vertically bottom but not working. Thanks.

Comment: Which date issue date or delivery date?

Comment: @BharathKumar both need to be at bottom

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gnqpbmrd/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `flex`, you can use the property `align-self: flex-end`.

```
.row-height, .col-xs-5 {
   display: flex;
}

#address { 
   align-self: flex-end;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gnqpbmrd/17/)

Answer (score 1):

apply css code for `#addres`

```
#address{
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

so its work

Answer (score 1):

Apply `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to the `#address`.

```css
.row > div {
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.row-height {
  display: flex;
}

#address {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='row row-height'>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div id="address-billing">
    <p class="address-label"><strong>abc</strong></p>
    <p class="address-content">
     abc<br>abc<br>abc
    </p>
   
     <p class="content" style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px"> abc</p>
 
     <p class="content" style="font-weight: bold"> E-mail:</p>
 
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div id="address">
    <p>
   
     <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><span class="date-field">Issue Date: </span><span class="issue-date"><strong>abc</strong></span></p>
   
    <p><span class="date-field">Delivery Date: </span><span class="delivery-date"><strong></strong></span></p>
    </p>
   </div>
    </div>
</div>
```